# Populating ListView from database

Tags: android, listview

Nothing is displayed on my ListView from my database.
Heres my code.
This is from Database Connections where data is gathered.

```
public Cursor getData(String hlth_cond) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String StringQuery = "";
    if(hlth_cond == "Highblood"){
        StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME";
    }
    else if (hlth_cond == "Arthritis"){
        StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME_Arth";
    }
    else if (hlth_cond == "Diabetic"){
        StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME_Dia";
    }
    Cursor res;
    return res = db.rawQuery(StringQuery,null);

}
```

And this code is on my main activity

```
public void showList(){
    String toPass="";
    if(Cb_Ar.isChecked()){
        toPass = Cb_Ar.toString();
    }else if (Cb_Db.isChecked()){
        toPass = Cb_Db.toString();
    }else if (Cb_Hb.isChecked()){
        toPass = Cb_Hb.toString();
    }
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getData(toPass);
    String[] fromDb = new String[] {DatabaseHelper.RECIPE_NAME};
    int[] toView = new int[] {R.id.textViewMenuSuggest};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursor;
    myCursor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.menushow,cursor,fromDb,toView,0);
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursor);

}
```

What could be wrong why it is not showing on my ListView ?

Comment: Why do you execute your query **2** times?

Comment: Conditional in checkbox. if one is checked it will execute it

Comment: I'd prepare the query string basing on the condition first, then pass it to the Cursor **once**.

Comment: I also remove the condition statements and still not displaying anything on my ListView.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[]%29

Comment: `  public Cursor getData(String hlth_cond) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String StringQuery = "";
        if(hlth_cond == "Highblood"){
            StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME";
        }
        else if (hlth_cond == "Arthritis"){
            StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME_Arth";
        }
        else if (hlth_cond == "Diabetic"){
            StringQuery = "SELECT RECIPE_NAME FROM TBL_NAME_Dia";
        }
        Cursor res;
        return res = db.rawQuery(StringQuery,null);

    }
I make it like this still not working

Comment: have you verified that there are rows in the table(s)? perhaps via `sqlite3`?

Comment: @DavidM yes sir there are rows in the tables.

Comment: @jellolicious try using this.getReadableDatabase() in getData()

Comment: what am I going to change there ?

Comment: how do you *know* there are rows in the table(s)? did you use `sqlite3` to query? or  `DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(...)`?

Comment: @DavidM I pulled out database from my device then checked it Via SQLite Manager.

Comment: @JagjitSingh Still not working sir.